# Cannot Select This File error on Nikon D500

Tags: nikon

I have a Nikon D500 with updated firmware to the latest version. I purchased a CFexpress card type B and formatted the card. I’m able to download my images to my Mac using a card reader. But when I try to download wirelessly to my iPhone, when I select on my camera “send to smart device”  then click “select images” I’m unable to select any images. I get an error message that says “Cannot select this file.” The images are not able to be clicked to be selected and I can’t download to my iPhone (using updated version of Snap Bridge).

Comment: Did you try to download RAW file?

Comment: Just to be clear, did you format the card in the camera itself , or elsewhere?

Comment: .NEF or .JPG? Did you try to download wirelessly *before* using the card reader to transfer images to the computer?